# How to call the AllocateAndInitializeSid function from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Can somebody give me a complete and working example of calling the `AllocateAndInitializeSid` function from C# code?

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375213(VS.85).aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI AllocateAndInitializeSid(
  __in   PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY pIdentifierAuthority,
  __in   BYTE nSubAuthorityCount,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority0,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority1,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority2,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority3,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority4,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority5,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority6,
  __in   DWORD dwSubAuthority7,
  __out  PSID *pSid
);
```

and I don't know how to construct the signature of this method - what should I do with `PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY` and `PSID` types? How should I pass them - using `ref` or `out`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [P/Invoke Interop Assistant](http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop):

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SidIdentifierAuthority {

        /// BYTE[6]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, 
            SizeConst = 6, 
            ArraySubType = 
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public byte[] Value;
    }

    public partial class NativeMethods {

        /// Return Type: BOOL->int
        ///pIdentifierAuthority: PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY->_SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY*
        ///nSubAuthorityCount: BYTE->unsigned char
        ///nSubAuthority0: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority1: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority2: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority3: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority4: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority5: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority6: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///nSubAuthority7: DWORD->unsigned int
        ///pSid: PSID*
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "AllocateAndInitializeSid")]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool AllocateAndInitializeSid(
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] 
            ref SidIdentifierAuthority pIdentifierAuthority, 
            byte nSubAuthorityCount, 
            uint nSubAuthority0, 
            uint nSubAuthority1, 
            uint nSubAuthority2, 
            uint nSubAuthority3, 
            uint nSubAuthority4, 
            uint nSubAuthority5, 
            uint nSubAuthority6, 
            uint nSubAuthority7, 
            out System.IntPtr pSid);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting .NET 2.0 or later, the class System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier wraps a SID and allows you to avoid the error-prone Win32 APIs.

Not exactly an answer to your question, but who knows it may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Platform Invoke www.pinvoke.net is your new best friend!

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/AllocateAndInitializeSid.html

Comment: Been there.
The 1st parameter is 'a pointer to a SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY structure' according to MSDN and pinvoke.net says it's IntPtr. Is it the same? How should I create thsi pointer?
Please post a _complete_ example. I tried everything I found online and I cannot make it work.